# Can I Replace SATA 3.0Gb/s hard disk with With SATA 6.0Gb/s in Toshiba Satellite c660 laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop and by default there is SATA 3.0 fitted in it. Few days ago, it stopped working. So I need to replace it with a new one. The problem I'm currently facing is I don't know if the SATA 6Gb/s hard disk (in this case I'm planning to choose Seagate ST500LM000 SSHD Drive). Please tell me will this SATA 6Gb/s hybrid hard disk work with my Toshiba Satellite c660 laptop? Also, I don't know much about the dimensions of hard disks. So please tell me in brief.

Seagate Hybrid SSHD Drive:
http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/

**Dimensions**: **Length**: 100.35mm, **Width**: 69.85mm **Height**: 7.0mm

**Form Factor**: 2.5"

*The current hard disk's info:*

**Brand**: Toshiba

**Model**: MK3265GSX

**Data Sheet**: https://storage.toshiba.eu/export/sites/toshiba-sdd/media/products/datasheets/mk3265gsx_datasheet.pdf

According to data sheet, it's dimensions are:

**Dimensions**: **Height**: 9.5, **Width**: 69,85, **Depth**: 100

**Form Factor**:  2.5" SIZE (7mm)

I'm planning to choose Seagate ST500LM000, Please tell me will it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

All versions of SATA are compatible. The disk will work at the highest speed or supports or highest speed controller supports, whichever is lower.

About sizes, you're only interested in the form factor. Desktops typically use 3.5" drives and laptops use 2.5" ones.

Comment: So this will work and get fitted properly, right?

Comment: It should be fine.

Comment: I'm just wanted to know that the height in Toshiba is 9.5 where in Seagate it's 7.0mm. What is this?

Comment: It's literally the disk's height. But it should fit, some disks are just made smaller because they can.